# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare function() previously declared

Tags: php, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I know that there are a LOT of questions with similar issues BUT I've been looking for the answer and still can't find my issue. I've already tried several ways to fix this but I can't find any solution to my case...

portion of my code: (I'm not using this function anywhere else)

```
function Validar($r)
{
$Msg = '';
$aError = array();
if (strlen($Msg) > 0) {
    $aError[] = array('success' => false);
    $aError[] = array('msg' => '1001');
    $aError[] = array('error' => $Msg);;
}
```

And I get the following:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Validar() (previously declared in
>   C:\wamp64\www\myProject-dev\public\cajas\reposiciones\controller3.php:20)
>   in C:\wamp64\www\myProject-dev\public\cajas\reposiciones\controller3.php
>   on line 20

So I added

```
if(function_exists("Validar")){
echo "The function already exists.";
} else {
 function Validar($r){
   $Msg = '';
   $aError = array();
   if (strlen($Msg) > 0) {
    $aError[] = array('success' => false);
    $aError[] = array('msg' => '1001');
    $aError[] = array('error' => $Msg);;
  }
```

So I can barely have a clue of what's going on and I got 256 lines with my message

> The function already exists.

followed by

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting! in C:\wamp64\www\myProject-dev\public\lib\DataSourceResult.php on line 39
>
> Error: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting! in C:\wamp64\www\myProject-dev\public\lib\DataSourceResult.php on line 39

And a table like this one: (sorry, I don't know how to make one in my question)

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>#</th><th>Time</th><th>Memory</th><th>Function</th><th>Location</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>0.0017</td><td>371568</td><td>{main}( )</td><td>...\controller3.php:0</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>0.0053</td><td>474480</td><td>include( 'C:\wamp64\www\myProject-dev\public\cajas\reposiciones\controller3.php' )</td><td>...\controller3.php:36</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>0.0091</td><td>476240</td><td>include( 'C:\wamp64\www\myProject-dev\public\cajas\reposiciones\controller3.php' )</td><td>...\controller3.php:36</td></tr></tbody></table>
<br><br><br>
And this repeats 256 times.
```

What does it mean and how can I fix it? Maybe you can guide or advise me a bit, I'm kinda new.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is controller3.php included or required from controller3.php?

Comment: It is included at the beginning after my PDO connection

Comment: @RickJo you should remove that. The file shouldn't need to include itself. That's what is causing this problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems that it was the main problem, I owe you one. What's wrong when I include the file?

Comment: It creates an infinite include loop. If a PHP file contains an `include` pointing at itself, then when it is loaded the first time it will execute the include, loading itself again, where it will execute the include again, loading itself again, where it will execute the include again, loading itself again, ... and so on forever until your program blows up.

Answer (score 0):

If someone has my same problem, @Don'tPanic's answer was the solution to the problem. The portion of code that had the issue was

```
if (file_exists("controller3.php")) include "controller3.php";
```

After my validating function so deleting / commenting it, was the solution and it worked exactly as expected; no loops, no errors.